# Route' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mern

Trying to make a MERN(Typescript) app and I'm not sure what to do in order to make my routes go to these pages/

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './pages/HomePage';
import StartGame from './pages/StartGame';

function App() {
  return (
      <>
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" Component={HomePage} />
        <Route path="/start" Component={StartGame} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Tried using switch instead of routes as well still getting similar errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this :

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './pages/HomePage';
import StartGame from './pages/StartGame';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/start" element={<StartGame />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

You have to use the element prop instead of Component to specify the component to render for each route.

Also note that you have to remove the empty fragments (<>...</>) as they were unnecessary in this case.